# mutt: rename IMAP folder

Tags: mutt, imap

How does one interactively rename an IMAP folder within the `mutt` MUA? Currently, if I want to change a folder name, I use the gmail web browser interface, but this is rather inefficient. Is there an equivalent of the unix `mv` command in `mutt`?

When I search for this topic on google, the search results pertain to renaming local mutt folders and files like `.muttrc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rename IMAP folder in mutt, while you are changing a folder and you are in the list of folders:

`'c?'`

(change folder, then use a list of folders).

When you are on the folder, which has to been renamed, use `'r'` key and you will be asked for the new name of folder.

Comment: When I was searching the internet for how to do this, I came across a post that said that one could use the `r` key, but I was confused because `r` is bound to reply by default. Now, it is clear that this applies only in the context of the list of folders. When I rename a folder by pressing `r`, I receive the following prompt: `Rename mailbox 'X' to: [C^[[C^[[C^[[C^[[` -- there are precisely 36 repeats of `[[C^`, which I must delete before typing the name. Do you know why this string of characters appears and how I can avoid it besides deleting it each time I choose to rename a folder? Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear for me... It can give you the IMAP server... Maybe it is some UTF-8 characters? I can only guess... I have in the prompt actual (old) name of the IMAP folder...

Comment: If you're renaming a *subscribed* folder, I'd also recommend pressing `u` to unsubscribe while viewing the list of folders, before renaming the folder. Otherwise, you'll be left with a subscription to a folder that no longer exists.